# Security of Trusty OS (TEE) Non-Secure World API

Tags: android, key-management, tee

Recently I learned about TEE in Android, [Trusty OS](https://source.android.com/docs/security/features/trusty) and its internals. I read through the articles on source.android.com and there is one thing I did not find there.

Trusty OS has its own [API](https://source.android.com/docs/security/features/trusty/trusty-ref) which allows TEE applications to expose *ports* and communicate with each other. It is also possible to use the TEE API to communicate between the Secure World and the Non-Secure World if the trusted application allows it during creation of the *port*.

**My question is:** How can the trusted application make sure that only selected applications from the Non-Secure World can access the *port*?

The `accept` method in Trusty Server API has the UUID of the client application as a parameter, but the documentation states that in case the communication comes from the Non-Secure World, the UUID is set to 0.

Is there even a way how a trusted application can securely determine which application from the Non-Secure World connected to it?

My idea of an attack scenario was that an Android device is compromised (rooted by an attacker) which means that the attacker can add a system daemon. The daemon uses the Trusty API to communicate with trusted applications and de-facto compromises the TEE even though the attacker does not have a direct access to it - e.g., the attacker's daemon can request encryption/decryption/signing of arbitrary data  using the keys stored by the Keymaster TEE application.

Is there any protection against that?

Comment: Only android system API can communicate with keystore and it is enforced by SELinux policy. As a root user can disable SELinux, it can get around that enforcement. Directly communicating with TEE does not mean you have compromised it. Root user can impersonate any app in non-secure world and can obtain arbitrary data from TEE on its behalf which is not a vulnerability but a design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can the trusted application make sure that only selected applications from the Non-Secure World can access the port?

> Is there even a way how a trusted application can securely determine which application from the Non-Secure World connected to it?

I've fielded these questions more times than I can count in reference to TrustZone apps in general.  So I will speak broadly and this applies to TrustyOS or any other TEE I'm aware of.  No, there is no way at present to authenticate a normal world app in a convincing way.  Anything a user/app knows/is/has in normal world, a sufficiently advanced attacker can forge.

One can restrict access via SELinux policy or Linux filesystem access and this in a way "authenticates" the caller (as having access).  But this falls apart again in the face of a sufficiently sophisticated attacker.

In the best case a TrustZone app is not useful to an attacker (ie unilaterally takes action based on an input the attacker cannot forge).  In the case of HSM-like TrustZone Apps, the best that can be presently said about them is they hide the key material.  But they, like any other HSM, will gladly encrypt/sign anything for anybody with the right access/credentials.